# If "on delete" is set to CASCADE, what should I set for "on update" for my foreign key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have 3 tables:

- **users** (id)
- **roles** (id)
- **user_role** (id, user_id, role_id)

Now, I want to set set a foreign key and I am not sure what is the difference between `CASCADE` and `RESTRICT`?

What should I set for `on UPDATE` and what fro `on DELETE` in my case where `user_role` is just basically a pivot table that pair users with roles.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **user_role** is simply a join table you are unlikely to need `ON UPDATE` - unless you intend to change **users.id** or **roles.id** for existing rows (which I doubt).

`ON DELETE RESTRICT` ensures that referential integrity is maintained, i.e. that you cannot delete a parent row (i.e. in either **users** or **roles**) if one or more rows in **user_role** refers to it. If you do try to delete a row, MySQL will throw an error.

(At least in recent versions of MySQL) I'm pretty sure you don't need to include `ON DELETE RESTRICT` as MySQL will throw an error anyway in this circumstance (in order to maintain referential integrity) if you have defined a foreign key.

Use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on both foreign keys in **user_role** if you want a row in **user_role** to be deleted by MySQL in the event that you delete either rows it refers to (in **users** and **roles**). An alternative to this is to do it manually (e.g. in your code) before deleting one or both of the parent rows.